# Concorrência com thread e banco de dados inserindo duplicatas

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, thread

Eu tenho o seguinte problema com concorrência usando Thread.
O código abaixo deve pegar o último número de uma coluna de uma tabela e adicionar +1 para salvar novamente no banco, o problema é que esse número não pode se repetir e por causa da thread ele está se repetindo.
O banco é isso .
**------
---- Items -------------------

id  | numeroCupom | qtdItem

=====================**
Não posso usar auto_incremente em qtdItem já que se o número do cupom mudar a quatidade de itens tem que ser zerada. O professor que passou esse exercício disse que tem duas maneiras de consertar usando o select for isert e outra forma que não lembro, eu tentei com a select for insert porém continuou inserindo qtdItem duplicadas.
O código atual insere algo no banco tipo

---

---- Items ---------------------------
id  | numeroCupom | qtdItem

**1   | 5 |    1**
**2   | 5 |    2**
**3   | 5 |    2**

### O correto seria

---- Items ---------------------------
id  | numeroCupom | qtdItem

**1 |           5          |    1**
**2   |           5          |    2**
**3   |           5          |    3**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package concorrencia;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



/**
 *
 * @author Francisco
 */
public class Concorrencia {


private static Connection conectar(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fiscal", "jp", "");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Concorrencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Concorrencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

private static int getProximoId(Connection con, int cupomId) throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select max(nr_item) from item_cupom where cupom_id = ?");
    stmt.setInt(1, cupomId);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    try{
        if(rs.next()){
            return rs.getInt(1) + 1;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }finally{
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
}

public static void inserirItem(Connection con, int cupomId, boolean demorar) throws SQLException, InterruptedException{
    int nrItem = getProximoId(con, cupomId);
    if(demorar){
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into item_cupom(cupom_id, nr_item) values(?, ?);");
    pstmt.setInt(1, cupomId);
    pstmt.setInt(2, nrItem);
    pstmt.execute();
    pstmt.close();
}

private static boolean seraQueVaiDemorar(){
    double valor = Math.random();
    return valor > 0.8;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = conectar();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
                    try {
                        inserirItem(con, 5, seraQueVaiDemorar());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Concorrencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

        }.start();
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Da uma formatada nesse código ai, seleciona ele todo, e clica em `{}`

Comment: Só você implementar um sistema de semáforo que resolve seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é fazer a busca pelo valor incrementado dentro do próprio comando de insert, mais ou menos assim:

```sql
insert into item_cupom(cupom_id, nr_item) 
values(?, (select max(nr_item) + 1 from item_cupom where cupom_id = ?))
```

O MySQL (InnoDB) vai bloquear inserts que afetem os mesmos índices (se houver índices) ou vai bloquear a tabela inteira no pior dos casos. De um jeito ou de outro o problema da concorrência fica resolvido.

Há algumas coisas "esquisitas" aí no teu projeto, mas não vou entrar no mérito porque aparentemente é apenas um exercício com um foco específico que não sei qual é.